# Alljoyn: LampStateChange callback is not received from MessageReceiver

Tags: alljoyn

I am using About+session Listener to control my lamp device.  To receive the lampstatechange notification i have registered the signal handler for lampstatechange at announce (after introspect is success).  But my application is not receiving the state change notification.  Following are the code snippet i did to register lamp state signal.  I am not able to understand what is happening why the callback is not receiving!

```
    const InterfaceDescription* uniqueId = bus.GetInterface(LampServiceStateInterfaceName);
    const InterfaceDescription::Member* sig = uniqueId->GetMember("LampStateChanged");
    if (sig) {
        QStatus sstatus = bus.RegisterSignalHandler(this, static_cast<MessageReceiver::SignalHandler>(&AJDeviceHandler::LampsStateChagedHandler), sig, "/org/allseen/LSF/Lamp");
        printf("\n RegisterSignalHandler %s \n",QCC_StatusText(sstatus));
    }
```

I have inherited the following classes of Alljoyn:
class AJDeviceHandler : public AboutListener, public SessionListener, public lsf::Thread, public PingListener, public MessageReceiver

[Note: The state change callback receives perfect when i run lighting_controller_service].

Comment: By changing the session opts to multi point, it got fixed.  Now i am getting the lampstate change notification.  Can someone validate is this alone is enough or something more i have to follow?